# Method of system/file/directory/application backup - Linux

Tags: linux, backup

I have various applications/directories on many different servers (Linux).

My method of backing these up so far have been to just use scripts/cronjobs etc to back them up onto another server. But that isn't really scalable.

But what I want is a single backup solution that will back up all of these applications/directories. I need it to have a management web interface that I can use to restore data when the inevitable happens.

I have done alot of research into this but I really don't know where to start, theres hundreds of applications (and they all claim to be the best). So I need some pointers.

Can someone in the know suggest anything? Apologies in advance if this is a bad question to ask here, I just know people here will have useful suggestions.

Comment: belongs on superuser, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on Superuser...ta

Entering more characters